# Security with multiple electric lines

Tags: arduino, ac, relay, ups

I have created a system using arduino where it controls 5 different electric lines. For example: 
Line 1, Line 2, Line 3, Line 4 and Line 5. What arduino does is, it turns on the Line 1 if it has power and if it doesn't have power it turns on the Line 2 and etc. Arduino turns on/off the 5V relay and it has at least 5 sec interval when switching from one line to another(in this case I have 5 x 5V relays). It is working perfect and I am very happy with the system, however I am concerned about relay fails to disconnect when commanded.

For example: If Line 2 was on and suddenly Line 1 also gets power and arduino will turn off Line 2 and after 5 secs it turns on Line 1. What if Line 2 relay didn't brake the curcuit? I think I will have a fire or something really bad.

My question is, can I some how make fuse so that never more than one lines will be connected?

See my schema:
The reason I am doing this is, in our office we have 5 different lines of electric and I want to control it automatically. Also I would like to see which line has power and being able to control it from the computer.

[image]

Comment: (1) What supplies power to these different lines?  (2) What is the load?  (3) Why do you need to multiplex between the lines?  What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?  (4) A diagram wouldn't hurt.

Comment: You really need a circuit diagram, please use the tool, they even have a switch symbol! When you say "turn's on line 1" do you mean bring it to 5V? Are these connected to the GPIO

Comment: Can you tell us anything about your load? What amperage load will this be driving; is it inductive/reactive/resistive; will there be a high 'inrush current,' etc.?

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB I know the relays that give power to the outlet can't hold 10A, but just to simplify I didn't draw another 5 relays. They will be triggered by 5V relays on the right side of the Arduino. My load is about 10-20A 220V. Also the relays I didn't include in this schema are 2 pin relays, so that I can put the phase and ground through the relay to separate each lines ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXkCLc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Mains selector priority.*

This circuit prevents cross-connection in the event of a relay contact welding or micro-controller going mad. You already have the components.

Comment: I like this idea. This prevents from something burning up, but I am not sure if I can control it from my computer incase if I wanted to change the order of it. Let me think little bit more see if I can make it work using the schema you drew.

Comment: Sure you can. It works as before but in the event that two relays are on (which, unless there is a stuck contact or logic error, should never happen) the lower number relay will supply the current.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can get rid of the ac mains-powered relays for your 'sensing' side to tell the 'duino when each circuit has available power. A resistive voltage-divider with a diode & cap can do the same thing with lower power dissipation and should give you a much longer lifetime.
2. You can use an N-MOSFET to drive output relays ok (but with limited lifetime due to physical switching stresses & possible contact welding), or you could have it drive an AC-switching MOSFET pair, as in the following (simplified) diagram:
   [image: improved circuit]

SCHEMATIC NOTES:

- No overvoltage-clamping, or any other protective circuitry is shown in this diagram, but it should **absolutely** be used in your final project
- The P-MOSFETS for the AC output stages **must** be specifically selected for this use. 'Normal' power MOSFETS will simply burn up their 'body diodes' in this configuration (without additional protection), rather than switching correctly.

Comment: Last bullet about power MOSFETs with body diodes.  I've never come across a power MOSFET *without* a body diode.  Theoretically a power MOSFET can be made without a body diode, but I doubt that such a thing exists in practice.  If you are aware of one, could you post a datasheet link?

Comment: @NickAlexeev Thank you; I mis-spoke there. While I can't locate the datasheet right this moment; I did come across a N-MOSFET datasheet for a transistor with 2 opposed body diodes, in what looked to be a TVS diode arrangement. It was clearly stated as intended for AC use in that datasheet. I'll try to keep digging for it.

Comment: I don't like the look of this answer for several reasons: no electrical isolation; if the potential divider ground connection is lost the Arduino goes live; any failed MOSFETs may remain on or any Arduino code or hardware errors will cause connection of two supplies (until something burns out).

Comment: @transistor I don't completely disagree. However, besides the 'no electrical isolation,' in what way is this not better/safer than the OP schematic using physical relays? Personally, with the # of times we've had to answer "why is my relay stuck 'on'?" questions, I believe that the possibility of a power MOSFET failing in a 'still conducting' way is a far lower total risk than the 1000x higher instance of a mechanical relay welding contacts. As far as elec. isolation goes; optoisolators could be added to each input/output easily enougjh. I think I'll 'tame your lead' & add those in. :)